# How do I permanently change $EDITOR to a specific text editor?

Tags: environment-variables, editor

I am trying to work with crontabs, and cron never asked me which text editor I would like to use, and I don't like the choice it has taken.

To my surprise, when I run `echo $EDITOR`, I get a blank output.

I can change it with `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano`, so it is set for the session, but as soon as I log-out it doesn't retain the value.

I want it to be the system-wide default, so I can use it with all users, but adding `EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano`, which is the location of nano, to my /etc/environment, killing the terminal and relaunching still returns a blank line when running `echo $EDITOR`.

As @CHAOTING says down below, adding `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano`to the .zshrc file in my home folder helped. Now, it is the default environmental variable for my user and for root, but running commands with sudo, I still get the wrong editor. Is there anyway the variable can be made trully global?

Any ideas what is going on and most importantly how I can set it up? Thank you in advance, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using zsh, you can put `export EDITOR='nano'` inside `~/.zshrc`. Zsh will automatically run this file. ( I think bash run `~/.bashrc` as will )

Comment: Again, thank you @CHAOTING, it does the trick for root and my user, but it is not system wide. Running the command with sudo does not use this environment variable. Any ideas why?

Comment: @Centaro, the `sudo` command only retains a small set of env vars for security reasons. If your local security policies allow it you can do `sudo --preserve-env`; read `man sudo` and `man sudoers`. Depending on your OS you can also try putting the env var in */etc/environment*.